# Recording video from ARKit

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, arkit

I would like to add a feature for users to record their `ARKit` experience. I'm taking the `capturedImage` of the `ARFrame` supplied by `session(_ session: ARSession, didUpdate frame: ARFrame)` and concatenating them into a video.

Unfortunately, `ARFrame.capturedImage` shows the frame of video captured by the camera, but doesn't include nodes placed by ARKit.

Is there any way to capture video coming from an `ARSCNView`?

I've tried [this library](https://github.com/AFathi/ARVideoKit/), but it has major bugs (no shadows, large stutter at beginning of recording). I'd also like to not use ReplayKit for this project.

Here is what I'm using to turn `ARFrame.capturedImage` into a `UIImage`, and subsequently, a video.

```swift
extension UIImage {
    convenience init(pixelBuffer: CVPixelBuffer) {
        let ciImage = CIImage(cvPixelBuffer: pixelBuffer)
        let size = CGSize(width: CVPixelBufferGetWidth(pixelBuffer), height: CVPixelBufferGetHeight(pixelBuffer))

        let tempContext = CIContext()
        let image = tempContext.createCGImage(ciImage, from: CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: size))!

        // This assumes we're using an iPhone in portrait.
        self.init(cgImage: image, scale: 1, orientation: .right)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually found a library to do this. It's [SceneKitVideoRecorder](https://github.com/svtek/SceneKitVideoRecorder).

I don't fully understand how it works yet, but the important code is located in [SceneKitVideoRecorder.swift](https://github.com/svtek/SceneKitVideoRecorder/blob/master/SceneKitVideoRecorder/Classes/SceneKitVideoRecorder.swift).

Answer (score -1):

You can try to use **ReplayKit**. I use ReplayKit in my AR App to record when I place a model to the scene and more.

Try this my snippet:

```
import ReplayKit

class YourController: UIViewController, RPPreviewViewControllerDelegate { 

@IBAction func shotVideo(_ sender: UIButton) {

    print("Video")

    if !isRecording {

        startRecording()

    } else {

        stopRecording()
    }
}

func startRecording() {


    guard recorder.isAvailable else {

        print("The recording isn't available now.")

        return
    }

    recorder.isMicrophoneEnabled = false

    recorder.startRecording{ [unowned self] (error) in

        guard error == nil else {
            print("Trouble with starting this recording.")
            return
        }

        print("Recording started with success.")

        self.isRecording = true

    }

}

func stopRecording() {

    recorder.stopRecording { (preview, error) in

        print("The recording is stopped")

        guard preview != nil else {
            print("The preview controller isn't available.")
            return
        }

        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "End Recording", message: "Want to edit or delete this recording?", preferredStyle: .alert)

        let deleteAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Delete", style: .destructive, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction) in
            self.recorder.discardRecording(handler: { () -> Void in
                print("Recording suffessfully deleted.")
            })
        })

        let editAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Edit", style: .default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction) -> Void in
            preview?.previewControllerDelegate = self
            self.present(preview!, animated: true, completion: nil)
        })

        alert.addAction(editAction)
        alert.addAction(deleteAction)

        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

        self.isRecording = false

    }

}

// RPPreviewViewControllerDelegate

func previewControllerDidFinish(_ previewController: RPPreviewViewController) {
    dismiss(animated: true)
}
}
```

This is my code, I hope I have been helpful :).